# Run query and insert the result to another table

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

```
import csv
import logging
import itertools
from random import choice
from string import ascii_lowercase
from collections import namedtuple
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile


DELIMITER = '\t'
ENCODING = 'utf-8'


def get_random_cursor_name(length=7):
    return ''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase) for i in range(length))


def extract_table(conn, query, itersize=2000, use_named_cursor=True):
    """
    :type conn: psycopg2.connection
    :param conn: connection object returned by psycopg2.connect.

    :type query: string
    :param query: SQL query string.

    :type itersize: int
    :param itersize: If itersize == -1, then fetchall, else fetchmany(itersize)

    :type use_named_cursor: boolean
    :param use_named_cursor: If true, then use server side cursor, else client side cursor.
    """

    if use_named_cursor:
        cursor_name = get_random_cursor_name()
        with conn.cursor(cursor_name) as cursor:
            cursor.itersize = 2000 if itersize == -1 else itersize
            cursor.execute(query)
            row = cursor.fetchone()

            header = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
            Row = namedtuple('Row', header)

            yield Row(*row)
            for row in cursor:
                yield Row(*row)
    else:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            header = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
            Row = namedtuple('Row', header)
            if itersize == -1:
                rows = cursor.fetchall()
            else:
                cursor.arraysize = itersize
                rows = itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter(cursor.fetchmany, []))

            for row in rows:
                yield Row(*row)


def copy_table(src_conn, dst_conn, src_query, dst_table_name, use_named_cursor=False, truncate_table=False):
    """
    Run query and import result to another database.

    We use null="" in copy_from, because csv library dumps None as "" (empty string).

    :type src_conn: psycopg2.connection
    :param src_conn: Source database connection.

    :type dst_conn: psycopg2.connection
    :param dst_conn: Destination database connection.

    :type src_query: string
    :param src_query: Query to be executed on source database.

    :type dst_table_name: string
    :param dst_table_name: Table name in destination database.
    """
    rows = extract_table(src_conn, src_query, use_named_cursor=use_named_cursor)
    with NamedTemporaryFile('w+t', encoding=ENCODING, newline='') as fp, dst_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        logging.info("Writing result to a temporary file.")
        csv.writer(fp, delimiter=DELIMITER).writerows(rows)
        fp.flush()
        fp.seek(0)

        if truncate_table:
            logging.info("Truncating {}.".format(dst_table_name))
            cursor.execute('TRUNCATE {};'.format(dst_table_name))
        logging.info("Copying result to {}".format(dst_table_name))
        cursor.copy_from(file=fp, table=dst_table_name, sep=DELIMITER, null="")
    dst_conn.commit()
```

This code, in particular `copy_table`, is used to run a query, write the result to a temporary CSV file and copy the result to a table.

An example of the usage is as follows:

Let's say you want to copy a subset of the table `public.my_table` in DB1 to DB2.

```
import psycopg2
import credentials

src_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=credentials.DB1_DB,
    user=credentials.DB1_USER,
    password=credentials.DB1_PASS,
    host=credentials.DB1_HOST,
    port=credentials.DB1_PORT
)

dst_conn = psycopg2.connect(
    database=credentials.DB2_DB,
    user=credentials.DB2_USER,
    password=credentials.DB2_PASS,
    host=credentials.DB2_HOST,
    port=credentials.DB2_PORT
)

query = 'SELECT * FROM public.my_table where product_count > 200'

copy_table(src_conn, dst_conn, src_query=query, dst_table_name='public.my_table_subset')
```

How could I write this code to be more Pythonic?

Note that I'm using Python 3.5.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you provide a little bit more context to your question? For instance, describe what your code does, how it works, or provide an example of usage so we can figure out which SQL driver you’re expecting to work with (you might also be interested in adding that information as a tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## psycopg2 already implements your `extract_table`

Since you're using [`cursor.copy_from`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) to load data into the new table, why not use something along the lines of [`cursor.copy_to`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_to) to write them to a file?

However, `cursor.copy_to` will translate to `COPY table_name TO 'filename' [ [ WITH ] ( option [, ...] ) ]` in its current implementation. You thus need to use [`cursor.copy_expert`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert) and provide the whole SQL query to be executed.

The `copy_expert` call will write to `STDOUT` or read from `STDIN` and redirect to/from the file-like object passed as the second argument (`file`). I believe the query to execute should look like

```
copy_query = "COPY (" + query + ")"\
    "TO STDOUT"\
    "WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '\t' NULL '' ENCODING 'utf-8'"
```

with or without the `HEADER` option; not sure how `copy_from` would handle it.

You can thus rewrite `copy_table` something along the lines of:

```
# Using format string because we trust the query, are we?
copy_query = "COPY ({}) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '{}' NULL '' ENCODING '{}'".format(src_query, DELIMITER, ENCODING)
with NamedTemporaryFile('w+t', encoding=ENCODING, newline='') as fp:
    logging.info("Writing result to a temporary file.")
    with src_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.copy_expert(copy_query, fp)
    fp.flush()
    fp.seek(0)
    logging.info("Copying result to {}".format(dst_table_name))
    with dst_conn.cursor() as cursor:
        if truncate_table:
            logging.info("Truncating {}.".format(dst_table_name))
            # It seems like we do trust the new name too
            cursor.execute('TRUNCATE {};'.format(dst_table_name))
        cursor.copy_from(file=fp, table=dst_table_name, sep=DELIMITER, null="")
    dst_conn.commit()
```

## Handling database state

The `dst_conn.commit()` at the end of `copy_table` is bad practice. You most likely want to use the context manager available on connection objects to handle that for you, especially if things goes wrong.

Using the connection's context manager is to handle commits and rollbacks only and does not close the connection when leaving the context block. So you can write, say

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(...)

with conn:
    # Use cursor(s)

with conn:
    # Use (other) cursor(s)

with conn:
    # You get the deal

conn.close()
```

You're also handling the creation of named cursors using lot of duplicated code. I understand that their use differ a bit from client cursors, but the creation can be simplified to:

```
cursor = conn.cursor(name=get_random_cursor_name() if use_named_cursor else None)
```

since the `name` argument is already `None` by default.

You can even go further by letting the user provide its own name using constructs such as:

```
def copy_table(..., cursor_name=None, ...):
    ...
    with src_conn:
        with src_conn.cursor(name=cursor_name) as cursor:
            ...
```

This way, you can have calls such as:

- `copy_table(src_conn, dst_conn, query, dst_table_name='foobar')`
- `copy_table(src_conn, dst_conn, query, cursor_name='foobar', dst_table_name='foobar')`
- `copy_table(src_conn, dst_conn, query, cursor_name=get_random_cursor_name(17), dst_table_name='foobar')`

## Protect from user input

As usual in SQL, you should not trust user input. As such, you might want to **not** directly use the provided query string. However you **do** want to build the copy query yourself. For these usages, psycopg2 provides the [`cursor.mogrify`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) method.

The copy query can thus be built using:

```
copy_query = "COPY (%s) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '%s' NULL '' ENCODING '%s'"
```

and then passed to `copy_expert` with:

```
cursor.copy_expert(cursor.mogrify(copy_query, (src_query, DELIMITER, ENCODING)), fp)
```

You may also be interested in providing a way to build the source query by binding parameters. In such cases, variable length arguments can be used to simplify handling of bound arguments:

```
def copy_table(query, *args, src_conn, dest_conn, dest_table_name,
               cursor_name=None, truncate_table=False):
    copy_query = "COPY (%s) TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER '%s' NULL '' ENCODING '%s'"
    with NamedTemporaryFile('w+t', encoding=ENCODING, newline='') as fp:
        logging.info("Writing result to a temporary file.")
        with src_conn:
            with src_conn.cursor(name=cursor_name) as cursor:
                query = cursor.mogrify(query, args)
                copy_query = cursor.mogrify(copy_query, (query, DELIMITER, ENCODING))
                cursor.copy_expert(copy_query, fp)
        fp.flush()
        fp.seek(0)
        logging.info("Copying result to {}".format(dst_table_name))
        with dest_conn:
            with dest_conn.cursor() as cursor:
                if truncate_table:
                    logging.info("Truncating {}.".format(dst_table_name))
                    cursor.execute('TRUNCATE %s;', (dst_table_name,))
                cursor.copy_from(file=fp, table=dst_table_name, sep=DELIMITER, null="")
```

You will need to use named arguments for anything other than the query and its parameters:

```
copy_table('SELECT * FROM public.my_table WHERE product_count > %s', 200,
           src_conn=database_remote,
           dest_conn=database_local,
           dest_table_name='public.my_table_subset',
           cursor_name='foobar')
```

Comment: Instead of nested with-blocks, can I write it like this

        ```with conn, conn.cursor() as cursor: ...```
?

Comment: @user74158 [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement)